# Set bit in Table A if values are present in Table B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, update

I have two tables, Containing up to ~10 million entries.

`TableA` which has 3 columns: `IDA` (bigint), `IDB` (int) and `CHK` (bit).
`(IDA, IDB)` is the primary key.

`TableB` which has 2 columns:  `IDA` (bigint), `IDB` (int). `(IDA, IDB)` is the primary key.

Now I need to set the `CHK` bit for every `IDA`+`IDB` that is in `TableA` and `TableB`.

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00,
 i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

Comment: @ypercube thank you for correcting - still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update a 
    set a.CHK = 1
from tableA a 
join tableB b
    on b.IDA = a.IDA and b.IDB = a.IDB
```